# ¿Cómo editar el panel de administración de laratrust?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-8

Instale el panel de administración que provee Laratrust contiene roles y permisos la ruta por defecto es /laratrust, quiero cambiar la ruta para solamente el admin pueda entrar en al panel y poder modificar a los usuarios.

¿Cómo modifico la ruta en el archivo de config/laratrust.php?

```
'panel' => [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laratrust Panel Register
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This manages if routes used for the admin panel should be registered.
    | Turn this value to false if you don't want to use Laratrust admin panel
    |
    */
    'register' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laratrust Panel Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the URI path where Laratrust panel for roles and permissions
    | will be accessible from.
    |
    */
    'path' => 'laratrust',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laratrust Panel Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The route where the go back link should point
    |
    */
    'go_back_route' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laratrust Panel Route Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These middleware will get attached onto each Laratrust panel route.
    |
    */
    'middleware' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enable permissions assignment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Enable/Disable the permissions assignment to the users.
    |
    */
    'assign_permissions_to_user' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Add restriction to roles in the panel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Configure which roles can not be editable, deletable and removable.
    | To add a role to the restriction, use name of the role here.
    |
    */
    'roles_restrictions' => [
        // The user won't be able to remove roles already assigned to users.
        'not_removable' => [],

        // The user won't be able to edit the role and the permissions assigned.
        'not_editable' => [],

        // The user won't be able to delete the role.
        'not_deletable' => [],
    ],
```

En la web manda a ver el código del archivo pero no tiene más información, sobre la edición o modificación de estas parte del archivo. por ejemplo en roles restrictions entra la llavs [] se pone el usuario me podran ayudar por favor

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas. Pero podrías usar las [directivas blade](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/blade-templates.html) que provee laratrus, o usar un [middleware](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/middleware.html#configuration).

Comment: Quiero modificar la ruta pero en web.php no aparace

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiando la parte del archivo donde dice: `'path' => 'laratrust'` y colocando la que necesitas?

Comment: ok para restringir acceso a esta ruta y solo a admin ¿se hace en este archivo o tengo que hacer un controlador?

Comment: Como te dije: Haz un middleware donde verifique el rol de cada usuario antes de entrar y se lo añades a la parte que dice middleware.

Comment: Tengo esto en parte de mis rutas middleware' => ['auth'] y la carpeta de middleware se encuentra RedirectIfAuthenticated.php ¿puedo utilizar este o es necesario crear uno nuevo?

Comment: Creo que deberías probar primero con los que [trae laratrust primero](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/middleware.html#concepts), sino, sí pensar en hacer otro

Comment: @gaidyjg ¿es buena o mala practica crear middleware para admin y otro middleware para user?

Comment: Pues es buena práctica en realidad. Todo depende de lo que necesites.

Comment: Voy a comenzar a hacer el middleware y a configurar quiero hacer primero la lógica de la app y posterior ya centrarme en los estilos